# Can I develop Windows 8 Apps without installing 2012 Express for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> Microsoft provides two free tools, designed to work together, that help you develop, test, and deploy Windows Store apps: Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 and Blend for Visual Studio. (These tools require Windows 8.)

I already have too many IDE's on my box. One of them is Visual Studio 2012 Pro. If I want to develop Windows 8 Apps, expecially the HTML5 variety, do I really need to install that huge SDK along with Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8?? Or can I just install some templates and add some nuget packages?

Comment: I thought it would already be built in to Visual Studio 2012 Pro. If not, you don't need to download anything more. It will work with Visual Studio 2012 Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can install the Windows 8 SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx